# UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

trying to update table in bigquery but got an error message stating

"UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row"

```
  update Data_Layer.ClassCategories cc
  set cc.MovmentTypeId = t.MovementTypeId,
  cc.IntensityId = t.IntensityId
  FROM
  AloomaTest.testfile t
   where cc.CategoryId  = t.CategoryId
```

Then I tried this query

```
update Data_Layer.ClassCategories cc
set cc.MovmentTypeId = (select MovementTypeId from AloomaTest.testfile t 
where cc.CategoryId  = t.CategoryId ), 
cc.IntensityId = (select IntensityId from AloomaTest.testfile t where 
cc.CategoryId  = t.CategoryId )
where cc.CategoryId IN ( select CategoryId from AloomaTest.testfile)
```

Got this error Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Sample Data for testfile
[image]

Sample data for Classcategories
[image]

trying to update classcategories fields ovementtype and intenstitype

Comment: The thing you've omitted from your sample data, and what the errors are **shouting** at you, if you'll just read them, is that `testFile` contains multiple rows with the *same* `CategoryId` value. The system doesn't know what to do because it's matching multiple rows based on your joins. You either need to pre-filter `testFile` to remove these "duplicates" or tighten your join conditions to only match one row.

Comment: Figured out the duplicates but it is still giving me  Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

     `update Data_Layer.ClassCategories cc
       set cc.MovmentTypeId = t.MovementTypeId,
       cc.IntensityId = t.IntensityId
       FROM
       AloomaTest.testfile t
        where cc.CategoryId  = t.CategoryId and t.CategoryId =(select CategoryId 
     from AloomaTest.testfile
     group by CategoryId
     having count(CategoryId)=1)`

Comment: If you are facing this error while doing any changes to the existing code then, please check that you have taken the latest snapshot of code and apply code changes to it. Have seen a similar case like this.